# Finding nested sequence in a larger string

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

The task is to find a sequence of digits, which can either be transposed by some number or inverted then transposed, nested inside another equal or larger set of digits. Input is from a text file. If the number is found either as is or transposed, output the start index of where it was found else if it was inverted or inverted and transposed, output index followed by inverted.

Example - If the number to look for was 67654, it could be found as 45432 (transposed down by 2) or 32345 (inverted) or 54567 (inverted and transposed up by 2)

```
Input    
67654      
14676545  
43234545679    
905    
#
```

First line is what to search for (67654) and the remaining lines are what to search through.

```
Output    
3    
7    
10 inverted    
14 inverted
```

My idea was to build a list of numbers which is the differences between each digit if the number to look for and that number inverted. e.g 67654 would make a list [-1, 1, 1, 1]. I would then loop through each digit of the string to search though using a sliding window to check if it appears. I did the same with the inverted as well.

```
diffs = [int(name[x]) - int(name[x + 1]) for x in range(0, len(name) - 1)] #name stores the fist line of input
invertedName = ''.join([str(9-int(x)) for x in name])

currDiffs = []
for i in range(len(name)-1):
    currDiffs.append(int(piece[i]) - int(piece[i+1])) #piece is the string being searched

for i in range(len(name)- 1, len(piece) - 1):
    currDiffs.pop(0)
    currDiffs.append(int(piece[i]) - int(piece[i+1]))
    Compare(diffs,currDiffs) # check if theyre the same
```

Doing my answer like this I find myself getting almost all answers incorrect. Any suggestions on how to fix my approach or if something is wrong with it would be appreciated.

Comment: start index or end index? You have output the end index in your example

Comment: This could be transposed by *any number*? Then it's impossible. Maybe you're not telling us everything.

Comment: @HariShankar The output is supposed to be where the occurrence begins. I think theyre all right in the example

Comment: How exactly does the transposing work? If you transpose a digit down past zero or up past 9, what happens (or is that not allowed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be the most performant solution, but it seems to work:

```
def find_diffs(inval):
    inval = map(int, inval)
    plain = [i - inval[0] for i in inval[1:]]
    return plain, [-i for i in plain]


def check(inval, against):
    inval_diff, _ = find_diffs(inval)
    print against, inval
    for i in range(0, len(against) - len(inval) + 1):
        test, inverted_test = find_diffs(against[i: i + len(inval)])
        if test == inval_diff:
            print i
        elif test == inval_inverted_diff:
            print i, "inverted"

inval = '67654'

check(inval, '14676545')
check(inval, '43234545679')
check(inval, '1467654543234545679905')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
14676545 67654
2
43234545679 67654
1 inverted
5 inverted
1467654543234545679905 67654
2
6
9 inverted
13 inverted
```

So what is this doing?

The idea here is that for a given input, we can translate the input to a list of values where the first value is always 0, and the remaining values are the difference between it and the first value.  For example:

```
1234 => 0, 1, 2, 3
5463 => 0, -1, 1, -2
6667 => 0, 0, 0, 1
```

We can similarly do this for any number to compare against.  So to compare we take the first N numbers from the number we are comparing against where N is the length of the source number.

In the last example, the source number is 67654, so the length is 5.  The `against` number is 1467654543234545679905, so the first 5 digits is 14676.

Using the difference formula described above:

```
67654 => 0, 1, 0, -1, -2
14676 => 0, 3, 5, 6, 5
```

So this is not a match.  You continue doing this, sliding the starting index of the `against` number until you exhaust the list.

The only other thing to consider is inverted.  For inverted checks, you can just multiply each of the numbers in the difference list by -1.  The offset doesn't matter since it is constant.

If you needed the offset value, things would be slightly more complicated.